# Where can I find mysql config file with all parameters?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, configuration, mariadb

Where can I find mysql config file with all parameters ?
I found some config files in

> /etc/mysql/

directory but there isnt any file with all parameters !

Actually I want my machine's mysql server to be remotely accessed. So I was finding "**bind-address**" parameter in the file but there is not one file with all parameters !
These are the files I found in this directory:

```
./conf.d 
./conf.d/mysql.cnf 
./conf.d/mysqldump.cnf 
./debian-start 
./debian.cnf 
./mariadb.cnf 
./mariadb.conf.d 
./mariadb.conf.d/50-client.cnf 
./mariadb.conf.d/50-mysql-clients.cnf 
./mariadb.conf.d/50-mysqld_safe.cnf 
./mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf 
./my.cnf.fallback 
./my.cnf
```

I read some articles saying that my.cnf is the mysql config file but there is no bind-address or anything this is the output of my.cnf file.

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.

#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

**mysql version:**
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.22-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

**Machine name and version:**

**1.** Linux parrot 5.6.0-2parrot1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.6.14-2parrot1 (2020-05-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux

**2.** Linux ubuntu-VirtualBox 4.15.0-106-generic #107~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 4 15:39:45 UTC 2020 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the settings you put in `my.cnf` or some other file?

Or do you want all 500 or so settings, including the defaults, such as in `SHOW VARIABLES`?

Comment: `information_schema.global_variables` should give same results.

Answer (score 0):

Try tables like:

use performance_schema;
select * from .global_variables where variable_name in ('bind address','port');

[image: SQuirreL select]

Comment: It says "ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'performance_schema.global_variables' doesn't exist" ! any idea on how what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the search path for my.cnf file by using the following command: sudo mysqld --help --verbose | grep cnf

The normal search path is: /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf /.my.cnf

And, if not present then create a /etc/my.cnf file.

Comment: Yes I have already tried to create my.cnf file listed on those directories or files(if there isn't one). and tried to append "bind-address=0.0.0.0" in those files but im still geting that port closed. (I know that 0.0.0.0 is risky but I'll change it later as soon as my work is done)

Comment: Please check your firewall if its accepting connections on PORT 3306 from outside the network. Use Telnet to verify the same.  
example:  #telnet {db server ip} 3306  or use this [http://telnet-online.net/] to check online 
And, to allow in firewall like iptables use below command:

# Append rule to the end of the INPUT chain
#sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -d 0.0.0.0 -j ACCEPT